# Use Httrack to download website on localhost

Tags: download, webserver, localhost

I have a Drupal website that is currently on my localhost. I need to show it to my client, but I can't see them in person. I can't find any free hosting services (that worked with a Drupal site), so I crossed that option out immediately. Initially, I decided that port forwarding was the best way to go in order for them to see it. While this does work, it requires my device to be on and running MAMP the whole time. This isn't favorable for me because my device has limited hardware that I don't want to waste on MAMP the entire time. The next solution that I came to was simply downloading the website, compressing it, and emailing it to them. To do this, I found Httrack which creates a offline browser viewable version of the site. However, the only way I can use it is by turning on MAMP, so that a server is available for it to download from, and using 127.0.0.1 identify it and download the contents. However, this is a very slow process, and seeing that the files are already on my device, it only makes sense that there is a better way to use Httrack. How can I use this program to download the site without using turning on a local server at all? Is there different software available for this?

Comment: You can't. httrack is not designed to be used in this fashion. If all you want to do is show them the site, why not make a few screenshots and send that over? Or arrange a meeting and let them interact with it using teamviewer.

Comment: You could give them a portable wamp server with the site on it. But that'd be involved. Your client would probably appreciate it if you just hosted the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTrack to scrape a site from your localhost but you have to use http://127.0.0.1 (loopback) address instead of http://localhost in the address definition.